# How do I enable params as methods in Hyperstack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, isomorphic, hyperstack

I would like to use:

```rb
class UserDetails < HyperComponent
  param :user

  render do
    H1 { user.name }
  end
```

Instead of

```rb
class UserDetails < HyperComponent
  param :user

  render do
    H1 { @User.name }
  end
```

How do I enable this as the default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class HyperComponent
  include Hyperstack::Component
  include Hyperstack::State::Observable
  param_accessor_style :accessors  # this is now the prefered param style
end
```